# Getting TypeError: t(...).Object is undefined when executing reactjs code on browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have written a basic code to start learning Reactjs. But I am getting below error in browser console after loading the web page. Also the web page is blank with no output being displayed.

TypeError: t(...).Object is undefined[Learn More]  browser.min.js:8:31612

Below is the code :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale-1" >
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1    /react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/6.1.19/browser.min.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="root"></div>
<script type="text/babel">
  ReactDOM.render(<div>Sameer</div> , document.getElementById("root"));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone please tell me if something is wrong in the code. I copied this code as it is from a online tutorial where it worked correctly.

Comment: The problem is here: `/react/15.6.1    /react.js"></script>` (spaces between `/15.6.1` and `react.js`. React library can not be found.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale-1" >
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.2/react.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.2/react-dom.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.25.0/babel.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script type="text/babel">
          ReactDOM.render(<div>Sameer</div> , document.getElementById("root"));
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: please dont post code-only answers, explain why your solution helps op

Comment: yes agreed! i just focused on code! I will take care of it next time. was my code helped?

Comment: @SanjayChabhadiya Thank you. It's working as expected.

Comment: You can edit an add an explanation to your current answer as well

Answer (score 0):

You should change babel-core to babel-standalone.

Take a look:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale-1" >
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="root"></div>
 <script type="text/babel">
  ReactDOM.render(<div>Sameer</div> , document.getElementById("root"));
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now it works correct!

You can read more about how to use babel in browser [here](https://github.com/babel/babel-standalone#usage)